# git push -u origin master fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:

Tags: git, github

```
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://github.com/Hisamar24/AndroidExample.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
   redirect: http://192.168.178.95/UserCheck/PortalMain?IID=E79FFF84-247E-7A03-4394-4F26B0436AAE&origUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL0hpc2FtYXIyNC9BbmRyb2lkRXhhbXBsZS5naXQvaW5mby9yZWZzP3NlcnZpY2U9Z2l0LXJlY2VpdmUtcGFjaw
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"  If you could, please add more detail as to what is your current situation and not just adding code. 
Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
Best wishes on your endeavors! Cheers!

Comment: Also, be sure to checkout the site for your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fatal%3A+unable+to+update+url+base+from+redirection

Answer (score 2):

You can see the same "redirect... " in [`Jan4V/jdownloader2`](https://github.com/Jan4V/jdownloader2/blob/b4bd7192bb74c7c9bcebb2db74c2a8b9304bf3a1/src/jd/plugins/BrowserAdapter.java#L393-L396) or [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow issue 2215](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2215#issuecomment-391025637).

In both cases, some kind of intermediate portail is the root cause:

> sounds like you might have some network restrictions/issues. The wget output looks like you are being redirected through a proxy when trying to access bit.ly links.
>   You may consider talking to your network administrator and seeing if they can allow you access to the bit.ly links used for bulk import.

Comment: Alternatively, consider pushing over SSH, which won't be caught by the proxy (but might be blocked entirely).

Comment: Thanks, I also think that it really is a network access problem, the network is very restrictive.